# using C++ opencv on ubuntu : cvCaptureFromAVI() doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, arm, pandaboard

I'm trying to use OpenCV library on pandaboard ubuntu 12.04.

So I installed Opencv2.4.2 version and the code is beneath.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main*int argc, char** argv)
{
    cvNamedWindow("origin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("hkleecv-desktop:/home/hkleecv/OpenCV-2.4.2/samples/cpp/captured.avi");

    IplImage *frameOrigin;

    if(!capture0 return 1;

    int key = 0;
    int fps = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

    while(key != 'q')
    {
        frameOrigin = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        cvShowImage("origin", frameOrigin);

        key = cvWaitKey(1000/fps);
    }

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

    cvDestroyWindow("origin");

}
```

The problem is this program can't grab frames from the avi file.
(this code worked well on VS2010 C++)

when I run the program on the shell with gdb, it just return message "Inferior 1 (process nnnn) exited with code 01"

I googled about this error and found a page posted by someone who had similar problem as me, but cvCaptureFromAVI() isn't working currently.

- http://cellprogramming.wordpress.com/2009/05/24/opencv-cvcapturefromavi-error-in-ubuntu-9-04/
- http://gijs.pythonic.nl/blog/2009/may/3/getting-video-io-working-opencv-and-ubuntu-jaunty-/

can someone tell me what can I do from here to make cvaptureFromAVI() work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cvNamedWindow("origin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("C:\\j.avi");

    IplImage *frameOrigin;

    if(capture==NULL) {
        return -1;
        cout<<"VIDEO NOT READ"<<endl;
    }

    int key = 0;
    int fps = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

    while(key != 'q')
    {
        frameOrigin = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        if(frameOrigin == NULL)
            break;

        cvShowImage("origin", frameOrigin);
        key = cvWaitKey(1000/fps);
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("origin");

    return 0;

}
```

try the above code...it works for me on windows platform...put the avi fie address correctly..

Comment: Oh I fixed the problem. I simply made a mistake on writing file address. with writing pwd command on the Terminal, I found the correct address.

Comment: Now another SIGSEGV segmentation fault on frameOrigin = cvQueryframe(capture); ... I guess I have to ask another question.